# xpath: unable to click on any checkbox

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

Unable to click on checkbox by xpath. I want to make this process dynamic in order to pass any parameter and then click where i need. However, i have tried with get input finding the text but something should be wrong because when i look for the parent of text (input) it goes to another property. How can i solve this?

**HTML Code**

```
<ul class="collapsibleList" style="display: block;">
<li class=""> 
   <input type="checkbox" id="000375" name="000370" class="">
   <div style="display: inline" id="000375_lit" class="">2.5.1 Formalizar</div>
</li>
```

**HTML**

[image]

**xpath try**

```
//*[text()='2.5.1 Formalizar']/ancestor::li[contains(@class,'collapsibleList')]/ul/li/input
```

Comment: Sorry, i edited the post

Comment: @cruisepandey Your edit for this question **clearly conflicts with author's intent** and **This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.**. The relevant `<div>` tag is **not** a child of `<input>`. Due to incorrect edits OP may not recieve effective answers for his question. Please take care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click on any of the *Check Box* with respect to the chosen text e.g. **2.5.1 Formalizar** you can use the following solution:

- You can create a function which will take inputs as the text to locate the relative `<input>` tag and click as follows :

  ```
  public void clickItem(String itemName)
  {
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='collapsibleList']/li//div[.='" + itemName + "']//preceding::input[1]")).click();
  }
  ```
- Now you can call the function `clickItem()` with any string argument as follows:

  ```
  clickItem("2.5.1 Formalizar");
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of click of the checkbox, you can click on the label next to it. It may work.

```
//ul/li/span[text()='2.5.1 Formalizar']
```

In java,

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ui/li/span[text()='2.5.1 Formalizar']").click();
```